# Redirecting from a .txt file to an executable file in Linux

Tags: linux, bash

I have a text file with all the numbers from 1 to 1000 (`numbers.txt`) and I have an executable file (`ex2-1`) that when it gets all the numbers from 1 to 1000 (it gets the numbers as input one by one) it print "Done!".
When you run the file you see:

```
please insert 1:
```

If you enter 1 it shows the same but with 2 and if not it will print "wrong input" and close.

I know how to read from a text file line by line:

```
#!/bin/bash
filename='numbers.txt'
while read line; do
echo "$line" #echo is just to show where the number is being saved
done < $filename
```

But is there any way to redirect so that instead of being printed to the screen it will go to the executable file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can run all these commands in a subshell and then redirect its output through a pipe to a process corresponding to a running instance of the executable file `ex2-1`:

```
(filename='numbers.txt'; while read line; do echo "$line"; done < "$filename") | ex2-1
```

However, as you read the file line by line, you could simply run `cat` on the file `numbers.txt` instead:

```
cat numbers.txt | ex2-1
```

or even more concise and with just a single process:

```
ex2-1 < numbers.txt
```

Comment: `test.sh: line 2: echo: write error: Broken pipe` put it in a file type sh and showed this...

Comment: @Velanar32 The reason is probably that the pipe is closed by your `ex2-1` when it still has some data to be read from. Try to run `ex2-1 <numbers.txt` instead to see how `ex2-1` behaves.

Comment: Both of these solutions worked thank you!